# Jquery &quot; in .html()

Tags: jquery

I have problems with the function html(), receipt by an object from JSON, data.text type, which contains a text with quotes and print it in this way: `obj.html(data.text)`

The string is printed as is without transforming `&quot;` in quotation marks `"`, and I need to print the quotes symbol.

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

As you can tell by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUs6c/), `.html('&quot;')` really does produce a double quote. Make sure that you're not returning something like `&amp;quot;` from your server; you may be over-escaping at some level.

Comment: yes, but i have problems with JSON object, console.log show object.data:"&quot;Hello&quot;" and obj.html(object.data) print &quot;Hello&quot;